# Work with not pre-known dictionary

Tags: python, coding-style

I have a dictionary, which may contain different content, for example:

```
{"name": "Dmitry", "surname": "Pak"}
{"full_name": "John Smith"}
{"name": "Joe", "last_name": "Smith"}
```

I need to print full name of a user. I see the following solution:

```
try:
    print dic["full_name"]
except:
    try:
        print dic["name"]+" "+dic["surname"]
    except:
        print dic["name"]+" "+dic["last_name"]
```

Is it a good coding style to build tree-like try..except spaghetti?:)

**UPD1**(@strcat)

```
print dic.get("full_name",dic.get("name", "DefaultName")+" "+dic.get("last_name",dic.get("surname", "DefaulSurname")))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the in keyword to check if a key is present in a dictionary:

```
if "full_name" in dic:
     ... do something
```

Using this, your code could then look like:

```
if "full_name" in dic:
    print dic["full_name"]
elif "surname" in dic:
    print dic["name"]+" "+dic["surname"]
else:
    print dic["name"]+" "+dic["last_name"]
```

And of course you can make it a one liner too:

```
print dic["full_name"] if "full_name" in dic \
 else (dic["name"] + " " + (dic["surname"] if "surname" in dic else dic["last_name"]))
```

Comment: enforcing this answer: "has_key(key) Test for the presence of key in the dictionary. has_key() is deprecated in favor of key in d." taken directly from the pydoc. so if "fullname" in dict: elif "name" in dict elif and so on!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method as a cleaner solution.

For example (could be spread out if you think that's more readable):

```
d.get("full_name", d["name"] + " " + d.get("surname", d["last_name"]))
```

Comment: Can you include some code showing how that applies to this situation?

Comment: I think, this method satisfy my needs:)

Comment: But in my solution you can actually put any number of strings in the list..like "sirname", "last_name" etc..n it will work..!!

Answer (score 2):

```
if "full_name" in dic.keys() :
    print "Full Name : "+str(dic["full_name"])
else :
     name = dic["name"]
     list = ["surname","lastname"]
     if any(key in dic.keys() for key in list):
             ls = list(set(dic.keys()) - (set(dic.keys()) - set(list)))
             name += " "+ str(dic[ls])

     print "Full Name : "+str(name)
```

Answer (score 2):

A good thing to do might be to normalize your dictionaries or to convert them to objects.

1. Normalize your dictionaries:

   ```
   dicts = [{"name": "Dmitry", "surname": "Pak"},
            {"full_name": "John Smith"},
            {"name": "Joe", "last_name": "Smith"}]

   for dct in dicts:
       if "full_name" not in dct:
           dct["full_name"] = "{} {}".format(dct["name"], dct.get("surname") or dct.get("last_name", ""))
   ```
2. Use objects instead of dictionaries:

   ```
   class Person(object):
        def __init__(self, name, surname):
            self.name = name
            self.surname = surname
        @property
        def full_name(self):
            return "{self.name} {self.surname}".format(self=self)
   ```

   And do one of two things: convert your dictionaries to Person objects or directly use them.
   To convert them, something like this might do:

   ```
   people = []
   for dct in dicts:
       if "full_name" in dct:
           name, surname = dct["full_name"].split()
       else:
           name = dct["name"]
           surname = dct.get("surname") or dct.get("last_name", "")
       people.append(Person(name, surname))
   ```

Based on your actual code, these examples might need to be revisited a little.